# Why setting a CSS role with :host ::ng-deep into an angular component CSS is not working?

Tags: css, angular

I am not so into Angular and CSS and I have the following poblem trying to define a CSS related to a specific component (into the .css file of a component).

If I do in this way:

```
.p-column-title {
    display: none;
}
```

it works fine. But if I do in this way (I obtained it from the PrimNG showcase example):

```
:host ::ng-deep {
  .p-column-title {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

The CSS style is not applied.

Why? What is wrong? From what I have understand the **:host ::ng-deep** is used to let be global style the CSS role...so maybe it is not the correct way declare in this way into the CSS of a specific component.

I think that I am missing some piece...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to make it like this:

```
:host ::ng-deep .p-column-title{
    display: none;
}
```